# Recycler View - Overlap items from right cuts the last one

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to overlap each element in recycler to the right for that I am implementing the itemdecorator class and it does but it also cuts the last view from the right, any help on this would be appreciated thanks.

```
public class ItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private final int mSpace;

public ItemDecorator(int space) {
    this.mSpace = space;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    //outRect.left = mSpace;
    outRect.right = mSpace;
    //outRect.bottom = mSpace;
    //outRect.top = mSpace;
}
}
```

---

```
eventDetailBinding.participantList.setHasFixedSize(true);
               RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerForParticipants =
                       new LinearLayoutManager(EventDetailActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
               eventDetailBinding.participantList.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerForParticipants);
               ItemDecorator itemDecorator = new ItemDecorator(-30);
               eventDetailBinding.participantList.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator);
               eventDetailBinding.participantList.setAdapter(new ParticipantViewAdapter(EventDetailActivity.this, imageList));
```

Image = https://image.ibb.co/hivnLF/Untitled.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem and it was `clipToPadding="false"` and setting `paddingRight="8dp"` on my recycler view.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/participant_list"
                            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                            android:paddingRight="8dp"
                            android:clipToPadding="false"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of padding you can check for the position like below:

```
 override fun getItemOffsets(
        outRect: Rect,
        view: View,
        parent: RecyclerView,
        state: RecyclerView.State
    ) {
        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        if (position == 0) {
            return
        } else {
            outRect.right = -80
        }


    }
```